# Resizing image taken from internet to display in android screens

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am downloading an image and i want to display it in a RelativeLayout as background. However since android has so man different screens, i am finding it difficult to resize the image according to screen size.

Here is my layout

```
[Top Bar]
[Relative Layout] ..width= fill_parent , height = wrap_content
[ListView]
```

In my resizing i am using this code

```
bitmap = Utilities.decodeSampledBitmap(in, imageView.getWidth(), imageView.getWidth());



    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) 
    {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) 
        {
            // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

            // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
            // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
            // requested height and width.
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }   

    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmap(InputStream in, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) 
    {
      if (in != null)
      {
        byte[] image;
        try {
            image = readFully(in);

            // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length, options);
            // Calculate inSampleSize
            options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
            // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length, options);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
      }
      else
          return null;
    }
```

However these are still stretching images and only in hdpi it seems something better, ldpi is worse, mdpi seems fine , xhdpi is bad too. Stetching is effecting. I can't fix the size of RelativeLayout or Use ImageView because It will then show space between Image and ListView..

What method should I adopt.

Comment: Didn't understand why you can't use image view

Comment: @shem resizing image for imageView will leave spaces on left right bottom and top View. ImageView centers the image. I don't want to show background between ImageView and ListView

Comment: so just set `center crop` in `scale type`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you not using the background image, but use [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) and set his [ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android%3ascaleType) to meet your needs.